# A layout for writing a budget?

Tags: formatting

I have to write the costs of a project in a budget. I would like to learn a fancy way to do it in LaTeX. Does anyone know where to find a layout for that? :)

Comment: Can you direct us to an example somewhere in the web which design you'd like? There may be differences between countries and cultures as well.

Comment: The [`spreadtab`](http://ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) package, which gives you some spreadsheet-like functions in a tabular, such as summing the values of cells, may be of interest.

Comment: The code Yiannis answered is OK for me. Anyway, if you know of any other layout I'd like to have a look too :)

Answer (score 10):

Best solution is to use, a tabular environment and for longer ones, longtable. Here is a scan of an actual example extracted from a report of mine,

[image]

I just use a simple `fbox` to box some numbers and `\undeline` to underline them. For some recurring items I use the `fp` package for automatic calculations (not in the example below). Here is the code for the above.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,imperial]{octavo} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding to utf8
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

%% Set some local commands and colors
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}
%\color{green!40!yellow})

\newcommand{\done}{\cellcolor{teal}done}  %{0.9}
\newcommand{\hcyan}[1]{{\color{teal} #1}}

\begin{document}

    \leftskip-1.5cm\begin{tabular}{lrlr}
    \toprule
    Details      & Amount  & Amount & 30 Jan 2011\\
    \midrule
    Materials received to-date              &              &148,349,154.57           & 149,387,782.00 \\
    Materials awaiting delivery             &              & 20,779,350.27           &  22,074,223.60 \\
    Materials still to be ordered by HS     &                                                         \\
    \phantom{ZZ}Mechanical                  &    158,030.10&                         &      38,351.40 \\
    \phantom{ZZ}Electrical                  &    344,162.53&                         &     287,394.98 \\
    LPOs to be released by HLG              &  3,337,934.08&                         &   1,276,883.12 \\ 
    Materials with HOK issues etc.,         & 22,692,102.00&                         &  22,692,102.00 \\
    \textsc{Sub-total}                      & & \underline{24,517,848.38} & \underline{24,294,731.50} \\
    \textsc{Contingency}                    &  2,000,000.00&                                          \\   
    \textsc{Total Projected Materials Cost} &              &197,660,733.55           & 197,660,733.55 \\

    Materials used in Phase II              &(2,000,000.00)&\\
    Materials damaged in fire               &(2,130,000.00)&\\
    Scrap recovery                          &(2,000,000.00)&\\
    Salvage value on ending stock           &(3,000,000.00)&\\
    \textsc{Sub-total}                      &(9,130,000.00)&\\

    \textsc{Total Projected Materials Cost (PhaseIII)} & &\fbox{188,530,733.55} &\fbox{188,530,733.55}\\
    \bottomrule                
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Note I cut the code a bit to change it to a minimal. I normally use the `tufte-latex` class or `Octavo`, depending on the nature of the report.

Comment: I think that a zebra effect would help the reading of the table. Don't you ?

Comment: @projetmbc Zebras have stripes to camouflage themselves from predators, they don't look good in type neither do they help readability. Generally use Tufte's advise to minimize the ink to data ratio:)